# Simulate process termination in ASP.NET application on task unobserved exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I was going through the following article [`ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/throwunobservedtaskexceptions-element) to check the behavior of `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions` setting when the unobserved exceptions from the Tasks are thrown from the application.

I was able to simulate the application/process crash with the following setting in a Console app:

```
<ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/>
```

Here is the console app code:

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

//Use the following config settings to enable the throwing of unobserved exceptions.
//    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
//    <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/>

public class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Task.Run(() => { throw new InvalidOperationException("test"); });
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
}
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

On running the above code I can see the correct behavior with `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions` as true i.e to kill the process for unobserved task exceptions. I was able to get the following screen after running the application which matches the documentation.

[image]

The problem I am facing is to simulate the exact behavior in an ASP.NET application. I am having an ASP.NET application running  targetFramework="4.8". I am not able to simulate the same behavior in my ASP.NET application i.e the process/application should be killed on facing unobserved task exception with `<ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/>` setting.

Here is the simple API code in controller of the application:

```
[Route("api/ping"), HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult TestPing()
{
    Task.Run(() => { throw new InvalidOperationException("test"); });
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
    return Ok("Pong");
}
```

Here is the screenshot confirming that I am using `<ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/>` setting in the web config of that application:

[image]

When I run the above endpoint in the browser: https://localhost:44364/api/ping I am no longer seeing the ASP.NET process being killed.

I am seeing no change in my ASP.NET application for tasks unobserved exceptions whether I keep `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions` as true or as false. I am already running the code in release mode. There is no handler attached for `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` in my ASP.NET application start up. I can also confirm that the `public IHttpActionResult TestPing()` method is being hit by calling the API and the proof is that https://localhost:44364/api/ping is being stuck in a loading state because `while (true)` in that code but the process is not crashing.

Can you share why the above behavior for ASP.NET application is different than a Console app for `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions` setting?

My goal is to simulate the crash of an ASP.NET application on unobserved tasks exception. Can you share a sample piece of code to achieve my goal?

Comment: Does the handler hit if you subscribe to `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event?

Comment: yes,  I can also confirm that the public IHttpActionResult TestPing() method is being hit by calling the API and the proof is that https://localhost:44364/api/ping is beingt stuck in a loading state because while (true) in that code but the process is not crashing.

Comment: @Raghav The big question here is that did you subscribe to the `UnobservedTaskException` event inside your `Global.asax`'s `Application_Start`? (as it was asked by *user1672994*). Please check [this article](https://evolpin.wordpress.com/2013/05/26/handling-unhandled-task-exceptions-in-asp-net-4/) for more details.

Comment: I want to crash my application on unobsered event. Why would I subscribe to UnobservedTaskException handler?

Comment: @Raghav Because ASP.NET application would not crash if there was an exception during a fire and forget task. That's why you have to subscribe to that event to be able to observe that such exception has occurred.

Comment: Does that mean that ASP.NET process would never crash on unobserved Task Exceptions?

Comment: @Raghav It depends on the .NET version. According to my knowledge in case of .NET Core ASP.NET won't terminate itself, so the unobserved task exception won't be an unhandled exception.

Comment: I am running ASP.NET 4.8 Frameork and yes I have this at the Application Start    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;

Comment: @Raghav Does the handler trigger?

Comment: I added that handler so that I can prevent the app pool from crash and yes that is triggered. But I need to simulate the crash behavior which I am not able to.

Comment: @Raghav If `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions` is enabled and you are not calling the `SetObserved` method on the `UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs` then it should terminate the process.

Comment: `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (_, args) => throw args.Exception;`

Comment: @Raghav Did you manage to terminate the app?

Comment: I was not able to. I wished if I was able to simulate that.